# Bulk index text field containing new lines with cURL

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to bulk index a file with the following format to my elasticsearch index:

```
{"index":{"_index":"articles","_type":"_doc"}}
{"title":"My Article Title","text":"My article text. \nNext paragraph here."}
```

Using this command:

```
curl -s -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson'  http://localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @/data.json
```

The problem is that the article text in my documents may contain new line characters `\n`, which breaks the formatting for a cURL bulk index, so I get this error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"},"status":400}
```

I have been able to bulk index these documents using the javascript API, so I'm hoping it will be possible to do using cURL, as I want to index these documents into my docker image as a part of the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do it on `Elasticsearch 7.3` and `Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (7.7)`.

1) Changed .json to .txt and just hit enter after the last line, saved and uploaded on server

`[root@host tmp]$ mv data.json data.txt`

2) Forced curl to append new line to output

```
[root@host tmp]$ echo '-w "\n"' >> ~/.curlrc
```

3) Curled to ES:

```
[root@host tmp]$ curl -s -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson'  https://localhost:9200/_bulk -k -u user:pass --data-binary @data.json
{"took":4,"errors":false,"items":[{"index":{"_index":"articles","_type":"_doc","_id":"QdsosG0B3nqkAGly3E6t","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0},"_seq_no":1,"_primary_term":1,"status":201}}]}
```

4) Result:

```
[root@host tmp]$ curl -XGET -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson'  https://localhost:9200/articles/_search?pretty -k -u user:pass
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "articles",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QdsosG0B3nqkAGly3E6t",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "My Article Title",
          "text" : "My article text. \nNext paragraph here."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me locally on Windows using git bash. Now to make it work on docker!